# 2 Apple TV's and 2 Remotes. Get 1 to talk to 1 and vice versa

Tags: apple-tv, tvos

I have two Apple TV's in one room. One new developer Apple TV and one older Apple TV 3.

The problem I have is either remote controls both devices at the same time.

**Is there a way to get the remotes to talk to their respective device ONLY?**

So the old Apple TV 3 remote would talk to Apple TV 3 only, and the new developer Apple TV Siri remote would talk to the new Apple TV only?

Comment: Settings>Remotes and Devices?

Answer (score 1):

Currently the existing Apple TV remote pairing process doesn’t stop the New Apple TV from listening.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201254

#### We can do this:

[Re: Any way to get the New Apple TV to ignore standard IR Apple TV remotes?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/62255#62255)

> You cannot disable the IR reception from previous generation (silver) remotes. You could, however, pair an unused silver remote with your new Apple TV so that the device ignores input from any other silver remote...

#### Or this

[Apple TV: Using a third-party remote control](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201856)